# Can I modify the code for an Adsense responsive link unit within the AdSense policies?

Tags: google, google-adsense, google-adsense-policies

Adsense now supports the creation of a Responsive Link unit (in addition to the normal Responsive units that were available long time ago).

However, if you create a Responsive Link unit and place the code in your website, it shows very limited sizes such as 728x15, 468x15 etc which are very bad sizes in terms of CTR.

The following article shows how to modify the responsive ad code according to your needs:

https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/6307124?hl=en

Does anyone know if the above article applies also to Responsive Link units?

What I want to do is to create a Responsive Link unit and modify the code (according to the article above) in order to show 300x250 Link Unit sizes which are not available normally when creating a Link ad. This Link Unit size of 300x250 has much higher CTR than the normal link ad sizes.

Can I do the above with a responsive link ad or its against the Adsense TOS? I have contacted the Adsense forum but nobody has answered my question.

I have tried the following code modification on my website and works fine (it displays a nice 300x250 unit consisting of 6 links):

```
<style type="text/css">
.link_unit_slot { width: 300px; height: 250px; }
</style> 
<script async 
src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- ResponsiveLinks -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle link_unit_slot"
 style="display:block"
 data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxx"
 data-ad-slot="xxxxxxxx"
 data-ad-format="link"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Do you think the above is against Adsense TOS? I would appreciate any feedback.

Comment: I am desperately looking for answers for the same question. I stumbled upon a popular site that modified the responsive link ad to assume a size of 300x250 (exactly the way OP has mentioned). But not sure if they did it in accordance with TOS. Experienced members, kindly advise.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this URL https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/6307124?hl=en clearly allows you to edit responsive ad units as well as link units. It works great but make sure you dont hide any part of ad partially or fully and comply with other Adsense terms and conditions.

Comment: My doubt stems from the fact that none of the examples in the document pertain to the "link units" in particular. Please can you let me know if you are sure that we can modify the responsive link units in the same way as responsive text/display ads?

Comment: I'm using myself and it works pretty fine.